# What else goes in a Python src folder, according to actual or de facto standards?

Tags: python, python-packaging

When using [src layout](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout) rather than flat layout in a Python project, is anything other than the project module expected to live in the `src` folder?

My understanding is that if I added `mypkg2` under `src` in the layout below, and published the result to PyPI, anyone who did a `pip install` would be able to `import mypkg` and `import mypkg2` (which might be surprising). Am I missing something?

```
project_root_directory
├── pyproject.toml  # AND/OR setup.cfg, setup.py
├── ...
└── src/
    └── mypkg/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── ...
        ├── module.py
        ├── subpkg1/
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── ...
        │   └── module1.py
        └── subpkg2/
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── ...
            └── module2.py
```

Sample layout from https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout

I haven't been able to find an example of a project with anything else present, nor an explicit instruction *not* to put anything else in there. **I am looking for a PEP or packaging document that answers this question.**

Comment: "src" means source, as in source code, so one would expect to find source code there and non-source-code things not there. But there is nothing logically stopping you from putting whatever files you want whereever you want to put them.

Comment: In a correct `src`-layout project, the only things present in the `src` directory are the top-level import packages and modules (sub-packages are in the sub-directories of the top-level packages, obviously). -- By convention each [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) contains one and only one top-level [import package (or module)](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package). If you had `src/mypkg` and `src/mypkg2` your project would have 2 top-level import packages, which is unconventional (but possible).

Comment: More important than knowing what should or should not go into `src` is understanding how `src` is treated by a given Python session. Once you understand that, it's easy to reason about how to access anything in or out of `src`.

Comment: (As far as packaging--and not *execution*--is concerned, there is nothing special about `src`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a correct *`src`-layout* project, the only things that should be present in the `src` directory are the *top-level* [*import packages*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) and *top-level import modules* (*sub-packages* are in the sub-directories of the *top-level packages*, obviously).

By convention each [*distribution package*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) contains one and only one *top-level* [*import package*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) (or *top-level import module*). And I guess that this convention is the "*de facto* standard" that is asked for in the question.

In the case of the example shown in the question, if the project had both `src/mypkg` and `src/mypkg2` directories, then the project would have 2 *top-level import packages*, which is unconventional (but possible).

Famous example of project not following this convention is [*setuptools*](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/), it has 2 top-level imports: `setuptools` and [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html).

I do not know of any authoritative documentation that clarifies this specific point of the `src`-layout, the closest I can find is ["*src layout vs flat layout*" on the *Python Packaging User Guide*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/).

Comment: if I'm gonna make only 1 top-level import module, why not just include the modules under src/ ?

Comment: @kukelia If it really is a single top-level import module, as in a single `.py` file then yes it belongs directly in the `src/` directory (not in a sub-directory of `src/`).

Comment: I also find the extra, redundant folder strange. I would prefer my_project => src => main.py and my_project => test => test_main.py instead of my_project => src => my_project => main.py and my_project => test => my_project => test_main.py

Comment: @Stefan In principle you can have more than one top-level [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) (and/or import modules) in a [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package). The convention is to have only one, but you can technically have more than one. -- So I could have source tree directory `something` that contains distribution package `blah` and top-level import package `foo` and module `bar`: `something/src/foo/__init__.py` and `something/src/bar.py`.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I guess in > 99 % of the cases, we don't, do we? Therefore, in my opinion, the case without extra folder should be supported, too. The name of the module could be derived from pyproject.toml.

Comment: That's not how it is typically done in Python packaging ecosystem. If you create your own Python packaging tool ([build backend](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Build-Backend), in this case), you can implement it so that it is possible. I do not know any Python build backend that has this behavior.