# I keep getting no module found error with setup.py

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

Not able to figure out what's the issue with this setup.py. After running a pip install . tried testing package locally but keeps throwing ModuleNotFoundError. Also verified that the package got installed under pip freeze list.

Here is my setup.py file and also am adding an ascii file structure for reference. Do let me know if you find something odd here, would really appreciate any help!:

[image]

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name="ebaSDK",
    version="0.1.0",
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    description="ebaSDK",
    author="sron m",
    author_email="sron@sron.com",
    python_requires=">=3.9",  
    install_requires=requirements,
    classifiers=[ 
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Seems like it is one more case of a project with an incorrect `src`-layout directory structure. You should not have your `.py` files directly in `src`. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76054318). Also check again [*setuptools* doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout), this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), and this [discussion](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/). Pay close attention to the directory structure.

Comment: What do you want your *top-level [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package)* to be named? How do you want to write your import statements? What was the import statement that triggered the `ModuleNotFoundError`?

Comment: Also, you should copy-paste the text version of the directory structure (since it is ASCII) instead of the screenshot. Screenshots of text or code are much less useful and usable than the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to add an additional directory under src, and add in code inside that.